# Room Availability Check SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, checkin

I am designing a hotel booking system. My tables are as follow:

rooms:

```
id, room, room_type, hotel_id
```

room_type:

```
id, type, hotel_id
```

booking

```
id,room_id,type_id, hotel_id, checkin, checkout
```

I am trying to make a room availability form which checks the booking table and gets all the rooms under selected room type with the status i.e whether the room is available or not on the given dates.

Here are have three conditions to check:

```
checkin_date < booking table checking date
```

Or

```
checkin_date > booking table checkout date
```

Or

```
room_id (with hotel it and room type as specified) should not be available in booking table i.e it has never been booked.
```

Hence, I designed the following query but it failed:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms where room_type = '$room_types' & 'hotel_id' = '$hotel_ids' AND `id` IN (SELECT room_id FROM booking WHERE (`hotel_id`='$hotel_id' AND `room_type`='$room_types' AND ( `checkin` > '$checkout' OR `checkout` < '$checkin' ) ) ) or 'id' NOT IN (SELECT room_id FROM booking WHERE `hotel_id`='$hotel_id' AND `room_type`='$room_types' )
```

here

```
$checkin refers to checkin date selected by user.
$checkout refers to checkout date selected by user.
$hotel_id is hotel id.
$room_type is room type like deluxe etc.
```

Any advice on what is correct way of doing this?

Comment: Try to use `AND` or `&&` (logical operator) instead of simple `&` (binary operator)

Comment: @camille hello i corrected it but still not working

Comment: @Sohail: What exactly do you mean by "the query failed"? Does it return the wrong result or does it throw an error?

Comment: @Pharaoh Its not giving the correct output.. no errors as such

Comment: In these situations echo out the query, copy paste into something like mysql workbench. Then try and work out what's going on.